# How do I adjust the Clock Indicator format?

Tags: clock, indicator

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04. The clock indicator on the panel is not following my regional settings format.

I edited locales and in all applications I have the right format of date and time except clock indicator on the panel. Tried dconfig editor but keys for clock applet cannot be changed. Tried to purge indicator and reinstall it - still the same. Is there any way that

I could change formatting of datetime indicator?

- Here is format I'm using system wide: `%A, %d %B %Y, %I:%M:%S`
- Here is format of datetime-indicator that pops up: `%a%B%d %H:%M:%S`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format "'custom'"
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format "'%A, %d %B %Y, %I:%M:%S'"
```

That seems to do the trick for me.  You should be able to do the same using `dconf-editor`.

In dconf editor, it'd be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes I found this sollution before but that is not working for me. There is no such schema as com.cannonical.indicator.datetime in my system for some reason. The only thing about time formatting I found is in schemas.apps.clock_applet.prefs. But when I try to change format to custom and formatting to what I want the message pops up: "Keys cannot be modified at this time". When I created new key that can be edited then I got warning: "This key has no schema". And now I'm stuck.

Comment: Finally I got it to work. This is how it worked in my case. First alt+F2 and gksudo dconf-editor (before I was starting gconf-editor). Nothing showed up o the screen but I beleive it started in background. Then I opened terminal and used commands that James posted above (thanks). And voila I got my clock indicator where I wanted :-)))

Comment: You shouldn't have needed to use `sudo`.  The preferences are per-user.

Comment: For some reason without sudo it did not work. Later on I downloaded dconf-tools from repository. And now I can see all schemas and do not have to use sudo. Glitch??? Anyway thanks, it's working now.

Comment: thanks for dconf-editor!  My preference: %e %b %Y %I:%M
%e = day with no left zero. Result:
4 Dez 2016 08:25

Comment: How do you use `dconf-editor` to change "Mon Dec 18 18:41" to "Mon, 18 Dec 18:41"?

Comment: this dconf setting no longer exists in 18.04