# How do I change the menu clock formatting to say "Mon, 18 Dec" instead of "Mon Dec 18"?

Tags: unity, indicator, time, dconf, notification-area

I have found [this instruction to install `dconf-editor`](https://askubuntu.com/a/41961/760090), but I do not know the %letter formatting to switch "Mon Dec 18" to "Mon, 18 Dec", nor do I see how to use dconf Editor to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [set `%a, %d %b`](http://strftime.org/) in the "*custom-time-format*" entry.

`%a`:   Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name. (Mon)
`%d`:   Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number. (18)
`%b`:   Month as locale’s abbreviated name. (Dec)

You must also set `time-format` to `custom`.